# Merging sorted Files using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, external-sorting

Multithreading is new to me so sorry for mistakes.

I have written the below program which merges files with mulithreading but I am not able to figure out how to manage the last file and after one iteration how to merge the newly created files.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MergerSorter extends Thread {
int fileNumber = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    startMergingfiles(9);
}

public MergerSorter(int fileNum) {
    fileNumber = fileNum;
}

public static void startMergingfiles(int numberOfFiles) {
    int objectcounter = 0;

    while (numberOfFiles != 1) {
        try {
            ArrayList<MergerSorter> objectList = new ArrayList<MergerSorter>();
            for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfFiles; j = j + 2) {
                if (numberOfFiles == j) {// Last Single remaining File

                } else {
                    objectList.add(new MergerSorter(j));
                    objectList.get(objectcounter).start();
                    objectList.get(objectcounter).join();
                    objectcounter++;
                }
            }
            objectcounter = 0;
            numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles / 2;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}

public void run() {

    try {
        FileReader fileReader1 = new FileReader("src/externalsort/" + Integer.toString(fileNumber));
        FileReader fileReader2 = new FileReader("src/externalsort/" + Integer.toString(fileNumber + 1));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(fileReader1);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(fileReader2);

        String line1 = bufferedReader1.readLine();
        String line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine();

        FileWriter tmpFile = new FileWriter("src/externalsort/" + Integer.toString(fileNumber) + "op.txt", false);
        int whichFileToRead = 0;

        boolean file_1_reader = true;
        boolean file_2_reader = true;

        while (file_1_reader || file_2_reader) {
            if (file_1_reader == false) {
                tmpFile.write(line2 + "\r\n");
                whichFileToRead = 2;
            } else if (file_2_reader == false) {
                tmpFile.write(line1 + "\r\n");
                whichFileToRead = 1;
            } else {
                String value1 = line1.substring(0, 10);
                String value2 = line2.substring(0, 10);
                int ans = value1.compareTo(value2);
                if (ans < 0) {
                    tmpFile.write(line1 + "\r\n");
                    whichFileToRead = 1;
                } else if (ans > 0) {
                    tmpFile.write(line2 + "\r\n");
                    whichFileToRead = 2;
                } else if (ans == 0) {
                    tmpFile.write(line1 + "\r\n");
                    whichFileToRead = 1;
                }
            }

            if (whichFileToRead == 1) {
                line1 = bufferedReader1.readLine();
                if (line1 == null)
                    file_1_reader = false;
            } else {
                line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine();
                if (line2 == null)
                    file_2_reader = false;

            }
        }

        tmpFile.close();
        bufferedReader1.close();
        bufferedReader2.close();
        fileReader1.close();
        fileReader2.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

 }
}
```

I am trying to merge sorted files with multithreading. Say I have 50 files and I want to merge all these individual files  into one final sorted file but I want to speed up and utilize every core by multi threading but I am not able to do it. And the files are big so they can't be placed in heap/RAM so I have to read every file and keep writing.

Comment: You can optimize sorting by splitting up the input and assigning one thread to each subset, but the final merge must be single threaded since you are writing out a single sorted stream.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: @JimGarrison  Pardon my english, I'll try to explain again. I want to merge multiple sorted files(I already have small sorted files) into one big final Sorted file. e.g. Say I've 9 files I merge them and they become 4 Merged file + 1 remaining file. Now I want to know how to merge these 4 files again and the last file too. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: Why do you limit yourself to merging 2 at a time? Once all the subsets are sorted you can merge them in a single pass.

Comment: Because merging in single pass will be just one thread operation ie. reading from each file and writing to final file (I already implemented that and it took lot of time). I want to do as concurrently as possible

Comment: Your code will be I/O bound unless you are merging completely in memory, which would limit the file size.  If you merge to disk in multiple steps, then you will be reading and writing the records multiple times (one per merge step) instead of just once, and that will totally swamp any performance improvement you might get from multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), but instead of lots of little sorted lists, you'll need to use lots of little sorted files. Once you have broken all of the files down into small sorted files, you can start merging them together again until you end up with a single sorted file.

Unfortunately, you likely won't be able to achieve high CPU utilisation as much of the time will be spend waiting for disk I/O to complete.

Edit: just read your response to a comment and it sounds like you are asking for help on the last step of the merge sort. The graphics in the wiki link above will also help you understand. So, assuming all of your files are sorted, here we go:

1. Read 1 item from each file
2. Figure out which lowest/smallest/whatever and write that line to the result file
3. Read a new item from the file which just provided the last item
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until all files have been completely read.

Comment: I have already done this and I have lots of little sorted files. The problem is I don't know how to merge these little files into one single sorted file. My above code tries to do it and can merge the small files but it can't merge the newly formed little bigger sorted files
Edit.
I want to do this using multithreading, like threads merging different file at a time

Comment: @user7082 Thanks for commenting, please see my edited answer, I think it explains what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Reading one item from each file won't be multi threaded, it will be sequential I want to do this using multi threading

Comment: @user7082 As other commenters have stated, the final merge will be single threaded by necessity. You can always perform many merges of a smaller set of files... e.g. if you have 6 sorted files [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], you could first merge them in sets of two (one merge per thread) [1&2, 3&4, 5&6], and then merge the results. Basically each merge operation is limited to a single thread.

Comment: This is exactly what my above program is doing right now, but I am not able to merge the output of 1&2, & 3&4 and if the number of files is odd then how to deal with last file

Comment: What is the problem? At the very end you have the final merged stream of 1&2&3&4, and the leftover 5. Now merge those two streams.

Comment: Just treat them as more files that need to be merged. e.g. 5 sorted files [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], first round of merging: [1&2, 3&4, 5], second round of merging [1&2&3&4, 5], third round of merging: [1&2&3&4&5]

Comment: You guys are right, the problem is I am not able to code/implement. Like how to keep track of new filenames, how to deal with last file etc :(

Comment: indeed... maybe put each round in a new folder to make it clearer, so round 1 takes your initial files and outputs their merges into the round_2 folder, then round 2 merge takes files from the round_2 folder and outputs the merged files into round_3. Repeat until only 1 file is output into the round_X folder.